# Slow Loris Attack Wi-Fi variant

Tags: wifi, attacks

I watched a [Computerphile video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vvKbMueRzrI). In the end, Dr. Bagley talked about the fact that a router can only receive/send a packet at a time, so if one device is slow it will slow every device down because all devices talk sequentially to the router. He also mentioned that around 15 slow devices are enough to drag the WiFi down to an unusable speed.

Assuming the attacker has the network passphrase, I wonder if it's possible to use the concept of Slow Loris Attack - having one device sending out really slow packets to the router to slow down the whole network. Or even without the network passphrase.

Is this possible? What would it take to experiment with this on my own network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the purpose is DOSing a WiFi AP, there are effective methods that do not require authentication, eg. beacon flooding or even de-authenticating legitimate clients (that should do it, even when the AP is still up, its availability is compromised).

As per the method you describe, you can send requests to connect to the AP at 54 Mbps (g) to slow down the network performance but that would only work on old routers. Modern routers can process multiple requests in parallel (real multitasking) by the usage of multi-core processors that assign quotas depending on the performance and priority of the devices configured on the network; without mentioning MU-MIMO used by modern dual-band routers.

Router vendors' focus is always performance in terms of efficient routing and speeds, so these situations are most likely considered when developing firmware.

If your intention is just to slow down the network and not DOSing it, I have an authenticated method that might work on must home networks: use an old repeater or router (old as prior wifi mesh) and hang it as a second network using WDS with its own encryption, that will act as a vampire sucking the bandwidth out of the main AP (that is exactly the test you are asking for).

Answer (score 0):

Wi-Fi is not really known for its robustness. Transmissions over radio frequencies are subject to a lot of interference from different sources - being malicious or simply environmental.

In the protocol, devices that want to connect to the access point (AP) will have to negotiate a speed at which data is transmitted: the *bitrate*. Generally, you will want that speed to be the highest possible value.

But, if your goal is to slow down the entire network, then you could configure your device to only select to lowest bitrate supported by the AP. Also, since you are connected to the AP, you will need to authenticate to it (meaning you will have to know the password, or there is no authentication in place). Experimenting should not be too difficult if you have access to a Wi-Fi adapter with monitoring capabilities. (And I don't really understand why you would want to fake your mac address...)

Even then, I would not call it a Slowloris attack.

The Slowloris attack is performed at the application level (e.g. HTTP). And the goal is to exhaust the server by opening a large amount of sessions while never closing them.

At the layers of the Wi-Fi, there is no concept of "session", and no resource is reserved for it. Which means that it is impossible to make the AP waiting for you. The AP gives a time slot to the devices that wish to send data. This effectively means that you cannot elongate the time to send a message. You have a time slot, and once it is over, you will have to take the next one.

Of course, a device could misbehave by sending data when it is not its turn, but this would effectively be the same thing as a jammer, and is not really related to the attack you mentioned. (Note that in this case you don't even need to connect to the AP.)

In other words, if you want to perform a DoS attack on a Wi-Fi network, there are much more effective ways of doing so.

**TL;DR**

> Can I slow down a Wi-Fi network by using a very slow bitrate?

Yes.

> Can I DoS a Wi-Fi network?

Yes.